# Sendmail doesn't seemto be reading the virtusertable on Solaris 11

Tags: sendmail, solaris-11, virtusertable

I'm on Solaris 5.11 running sendmail. Local usernames are of the form <letters><numbers> (e.g. hn06511). In the past we used aliases to make  point to <username>@olddomain.com.

> <username> <username>@olddomain.com

Now there's a new email address scheme and a new domain. Now email addresses are of the form <firstname>.<lastname>@newdomain.com.

So I changed the aliases to be:

> <username> <firstname>.<lastname>@newdomain.com

This works, however <username>@olddomain.com no longer works. To add insult to injury, there are many scripts with hardcoded email addresses to the old style.

So I want to change <username>@olddomain.com -> <firstname><lastname>@newdomain.com. I thought I could use virtusertables to accomplish this so I made a virtusertable that contains:

> @olddomain.com %1

Supposedly that should take <anybody>@olddomain.com and route it to just the username (%1). I hoped that then the aliases I have defined would translate <username> -> <firstname>.<lastname>@newdomain.com. But as far as I can see sendmail is ignoring this virtusertable completely and attempting delivery to <username>@olddomain.com and, of course, failing.

AFAICT I formated the virtusertable properly and ran makemap (should I be using dbm or hash? I've seen both). AFAICT I have put in the proper FEATURE and done the make and made sure the generated sendmail.cf is in the proper place. I've seen FEATURE expressed as both

> FEATURE(`virtusertable',`dbm -o /etc/mail/virtusertable')

and

> FEATURE(`virtusertable',`hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable')

But neither work.

What kind of debugging or other info can I provide and try?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

## virtusertable debug commands for user root

Look for `@oldomain.com` entry in virtusertable

```
echo '/map virtusertable xxx@oldomain.com' | sendmail -bt
```

Check if sendmail checks virtusertable for olddomain.com email addresses

```
echo '3,0 john.doe@olddomain.com' | sendmail -d60.5 -bt
```

`-d60.5` tracks maps' lookups (also virtusertable lookups).

---

More hints:

1. `m4` expects another quoting

   ```
   FEATURE(virtusertable,`hash /etc/mail/virtusertable')
   ```
2. Do not make virtusertable optional.  Remove `-o` from the `FEATURE` line.
   With `-o` sendmail ignores missing virtusertable.
3. Sendmail uses compiled version of virtusertable.  Use `makemap` to compile virtusertable.
4. virtusertable is consulted only for local email domains (`$=w`) and `$={VirtHost}` domains.

   Use the command below as root to get both list of domains

   ```
   echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt
   echo '$={VirtHost}' | sendmail -bt
   ```

Comment: I had the funky `' quoting around virtusertable in the FEATURE line. I think this site ate the "`" character. As your line didn't have that I removed that. I also removed the -o. I had done makemap for the virtualusertable to produce virtusertable.db in /etc/mail.   

    $ echo '/map hn06511@gdc4s.com' | sendmail -bt
    ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
    Enter <ruleset> <address>
    No key specified
    >

Comment: This comment system sucks. Doesn't honor markups, limits me to way too few characters. I'll just tack on my response to the original OP I guess...

Comment: I'd love to post the output of some of these commands but I don't see a way to do that! Here's what I can post:

$ echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> [IPv6:::1]
[10.100.13.21]
loghost
mailhost.gddsi.com
localhost
rdeadm1
[127.0.0.1]
mailhost
$ echo '$={VirtHost}' | sendmail -bt
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> > Wizard Rdeadm1:

Comment: echo '3,0 hn06511@gdc4s.com' | sendmail -d60.5 -bt
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> canonify           input: hn06511 @ gdc4s . com
Canonify2          input: hn06511 < @ gdc4s . com >
map_lookup(host, gdc4s.com, %0=gdc4s.com) => gdc4s.com: Name server timeout
NOT FOUND (75)
map_lookup(host, gdc4s.com) tempfail: errno=0
Canonify2        returns: hn06511 < @ gdc4s . com >
canonify         returns: hn06511 < @ gdc4s . com >
== Ruleset 3,0 (3) status 75

Comment: Continued...

parse              input: hn06511 < @ gdc4s . com >
Parse0             input: hn06511 < @ gdc4s . com >
Parse0           returns: hn06511 < @ gdc4s . com >
ParseLocal         input: hn06511 < @ gdc4s . com >
ParseLocal       returns: hn06511 < @ gdc4s . com >
Parse1             input: hn06511 < @ gdc4s . com >
MailerToTriple     input: < smtp-west . gd-ms . us . > hn06511 < @ gdc4s . com >

Comment: Continued again...

MailerToTriple   returns: $# relay $@ smtp-west . gd-ms . us . $: hn06511 < @ gdc4s . com >
Parse1           returns: $# relay $@ smtp-west . gd-ms . us . $: hn06511 < @ gdc4s . com >
parse            returns: $# relay $@ smtp-west . gd-ms . us . $: hn06511 < @ gdc4s . com >\